# PHP Loop with smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

This is my PHP code with smarty.

```
<p>
    <label for="dob">{$smarty.const.LBL_DATE_OF_BIRTH}</label>
    <span>
        <select class="left" id="bday" name="bday" style="width:60px;" >
            <option value="">- {$smarty.const.LBL_DAY} -</option>{$days}
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
```

and my PHP code is

```
for($bd=1;$bd<=31;$bd++)
{
    $bdkey=($bd<10)?"0".$bd:$bd;
    $selected='';
    if($bdkey==date("d",strtotime($data['dob']))) $selected ='selected';
    $days.="<option value=".$bdkey." $selected >".$bdkey."</option>";
}

$smarty->assign('days',$days);
```

This value is inserted in DB. But its not selected the value. Like, if I select 15, and save, it inserted DB. But not showing selected value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use: `$selected=' selected="selected" `;`

Comment: @Oscar Pérez No, this not work

Comment: Probably your `if($bdkey==date("d",strtotime($data['dob'])))` statement returns false. Print out each check to see, why don't you get the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the Smarty way, Smarty has the excellent function [html_options](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl) to create html select fields.

PHP:

```
$days = array("- ".LBL_DAY." -");
for($bd=1;$bd<=31;$bd++) {
    $days[] = ($bd<10)?"0".$bd:$bd;
}

$smarty->assign("days", $days);
$day = date("d",strtotime($data['dob']));
$smarty->assign("dob", $day);
```

Smarty:

```
<p>
    <label for="dob">{$smarty.const.LBL_DATE_OF_BIRTH}</label>
    <span>
        {html_options values=$days output=$days selected=$dob class="left" id="bday" name="bday" style="width:60px;"}
    </span>
</p>
```

This will use the array and the data from PHP and create the complete select element including all options, with the currently stored already selected.